# Functional programming and immutability in Rust

Tags: functional-programming, rust, immutability

I'm writing a small Sudoku game in Rust.
A class named `GameState` holds all information necessary for the game to be (dis)played, a class named `Renderer` uses a `GameState` to display the GUI, and a class named `Controller` receives the user input, and converts those into data to update the `GameState`.

I am having issues understanding how to apply "good" functional programming practices when it comes to updating those values.

As of now, my controller owns the `GameState`:

```
pub struct Controller {
     pub game_state: GameState,
}
```

My `Renderer` simply uses a reference to a `GameState` when necessary:

```
window.draw_2d(&e, |c, g| {
    clear([1.0; 4], g);

    let t = c.transform;

    renderer.draw_all(&controller.game_state, t, g);
});
```

When I update my `GameState` (from my `Controller`'s method that receives user input), should I simply have everything mutable (which is not what I "should" be doing in FP), like this:

```
fn button(&mut self, key: Key) {
    use piston_window::Key::*;
    let new_val;

    match key {
        D1 => new_val = 1,
        D2 => new_val = 2,
        D3 => new_val = 3,
        D4 => new_val = 4,
        D5 => new_val = 5,
        D6 => new_val = 6,
        D7 => new_val = 7,
        D8 => new_val = 8,
        D9 => new_val = 9,
        _ => return,
    }

    let cell = self.game_state.selected_cell_index;
    self.game_state.grid[cell.row][cell.col] = Cell::Value(new_val);
}
```

Or have only a mutable `Controller`, with a new `GameState`:

```
fn button(&mut self, key: Key) {
    use piston_window::Key::*;
    let new_val;

    match key {
        D1 => new_val = 1,
        D2 => new_val = 2,
        D3 => new_val = 3,
        D4 => new_val = 4,
        D5 => new_val = 5,
        D6 => new_val = 6,
        D7 => new_val = 7,
        D8 => new_val = 8,
        D9 => new_val = 9,
        _ => return,
    }

    let cell = self.game_state.selected_cell_index;
    self.game_state = self.game_state.play(cell, new_val);
}
```

Or should I just have both data structures immutable and recreated ? In my case I guess in the end not having the `Controller` owning the `GameState` is probably as good, but in general I wonder how people deal with this issue. Shouldn't it be obvious, or am I simply missing the point of functional programming as a whole?

Comment: You are asking for people's opinions on how to structure your code, even worse, what "good" functional programming is. This is not on-topic for Stack Overflow: *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions*

Comment: If you have working code, this *may* be a good fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/32521). As an additional nit, Rust doesn't have "classes". It's also not required to write in a fully functional style in Rust, although you often can.

Comment: A match is also an expression. Remove the assignments of the variable and instead assign the match expression to the variable instead.